# The sentence structure of "てもいない"

Tags: particle-も

Recently I found an intereseting sentence pattern "てもいない".

聞いてもいない in 
聞いてもない話を聞かされる

やってもいない in 
やってもいないことを出来ないと言わない

話してもいない in
いきなりマイナス!?話してもいない相手への印象を悪くする行動

思ってもいない in
思ってもないことを平気で言える女

The question I want to ask is, is it possible to omit the も, or it would sound wierd？

Comment: ericさん 原文は「聞いてもない」「思ってもない」だったのになんで「聞いてもいない」「思ってもいない」に変えちゃうの

Comment: @Chocolate, I edited it because the question was about “てもいない” pattern, so the parts that said "てもない" were obviously typographical errors on the part of the questioner.

Comment: 「聞いてもない」「思ってもない」are not typographical errors. These are just common shortened/contracted forms.

Comment: I can understand that, but  if you read the question, "what does the word GIVE mean, in "gives me the books" ?  ... wouldn't you change one of those words so that they both match? That's literally all I did.

Comment: ^ 間違い・タイポでもないのに原文勝手に変えちゃうってどうなんですかね・・・

Comment: The unnecessary editing obviously needs to be canceled.   Someone who knows how to do it, please do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this も is close to "even".

You can rephrase your examples as 聞いてさえもいない話, やってさえもいないこと and 話してさえもいない相手.

You can omit the も and the sentence loses the meaning of "even".

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the も would change the verb to mean something slightly different.

聞いてもいない = not even listening
聞いていない = not listening

やってもいない = not even doing it 
やっていない = not doing it

and so on.

Comment: This answer appears to suggest that ～ている is progressive ('is V-ing') while ～て**も**いる is perfective ('have V-ed'), but I don't think the choice between the meanings of ～ている depends on whether or not も is there.  One good reference for the meanings of ～ている, freely available online, is Mamori Sugita's 2009 dissertation: http://www.mamori.com/Sugita2009.pdf

Comment: @snailboat , so, you agree with my first sentence but not my interpretations of the exact meanings? If perfective is the wrong tense translation, what is the more accurate one?

Comment: 「聞いて**も**いない」"haven't *even* heard" 「やって**も**いない」"haven't *even* done yet" って書くなら、「聞いていない」「やっていない」には "haven't heard" "haven't done yet" を書かないと比較にならないのでは・・？「聞いていない」、「やっていない」は "haven't heard yet", "haven't done yet" って意味と "is not hearing (now)", "is not doing (now)" の(少なくとも)両方の意味があるので。

Comment: @Chocolate , I can't tell from your comment whether you are supporting my answer or adding to snailboat's comment about how my answer doesn't quite work. I find that in spoken Japanese, tense interpretations can be very fluid. Technically 聞いてもいない would I suppose be better translated as "not even hearing/listening"... is that what you are pointing out?

Comment: I'll try rephrasing.  Your answer suggests that the difference between these two meanings (*be V-ing* and *have V-ed*) depends on whether も is there.  However, it can have either meaning regardless of whether も is there.

Comment: huh... so you are saying that も changes nothing? I would expect も to make the "even" expression. Or at least, make it emphasized. I don't think I've ever heard someone use も when they were NOT trying to express the idea of "even" ... your assertion doesn't explain how the OTHER answer, which says essentially the same thing I said, is both plus 1ed and edited for clarity by Chocolate, without removing the "even" aspect... As  I understand it Chocolate is a native Japanese speaker. Not sure whether Yuuichi is Japanese or if that's just a Japanese pseudonym.

Comment: Hmm, we don't appear to be communicating very effectively.  I'll try a third time.  No, I do believe the "even" meaning changes; that's what も adds in this case, as Yuuichi Tam points out.  But your answer suggests that the examples with も have the 'have V-ed' meaning, while the examples without も have the 'be V-ing' meaning, which is strange since simply adding or removing も shouldn't cause that shift in meaning, particularly when the rest of the sentence gives enough context to understand which of the aspectual meanings ～ている should have.

Comment: ah.  Ok. That I can fix. I do swear though, that I HAVE heard Japanese people use てもいない form in situations where I would normally use "have not even .... yet".  Still, I will edit it so the tenses agree.

Comment: ^ ほんじゃ「聞いてもいない = have not even heard 聞いていない = have not heard やってもいない = have not even done やっていない = have not done」  にしたらいいやん・・・

Comment: ...that's the way those phrases have always sounded to me, in certain contexts, yes. But ていない /ている　are of course grammatically the equivalent of "not __-ing/ -ing", and that meaning is also made clear by context. ....  If a Japanese person said to you: なに、今の話！？聞いていないよ、それ！ It's most naturally translated as "What are you talking about!? I've never heard that!  .....  or have I totally gone off and gotten lost in my own head here?

Comment: ^ As I said in my previous comment, 「聞いていない」「やっていない」can mean EITHER "I haven't heard" "haven't done" OR "I am not listening" "I am not doing", depending on context. 聞いてない in 「何それ、聞いてないよ！」 would naturally be interpreted as "I haven't heard", rather than "What, I'm not listening!"